# Java regexp grouping and + operator (Obtaining multiple values of a group)

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering if is it possible to obtain all the matches of a group with a + operator on a java regular expression.

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "Start: First match, second match, third match.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Start:\\s*(([\\w\\s]+),?\\s*)+.");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Regular expression Match: "+ m.group(0));
        System.out.println("Group 1: "+ m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Group 2: "+ m.group(2));
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Regular expression Match: Start: First match, second match, third match.
Group 1: third match
Group 2: third match
```

Despite group 2 matched 3 times "First match, " "second match, " "third match" due to the second "+" operator that is on the Regexp we can access just the last one on match.group(2).

My questions is:

¿There exist a way to access the other hits of the group 2 on that expression or when a + operator causes multiple match on a group only the last one can be accesed?.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, you can't match *n* groups using + like this.

However, if you are looking to solve this problem in Java then using a `Scanner` to break on the delimiters may help:

```
    String input = "Start: First match, second match, third match.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Start:|\\s*,");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(p);
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Matched: " + s.next());
    }
```

This prints out:

```
Matched:  First match
Matched:  second match
Matched:  third match.
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

`There exist a way to access the other hits of the group 2 on that expression or when a + operator causes multiple match on a group only the last one can be accesed?.`

Answer is NO, if same group matches some text multiple times then you can only access last matched text.

There are of course other ways to return multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may not be possible with your regular expression.

As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg):

> The captured input associated with a group is always the subsequence
>   that the group most recently matched. If a group is evaluated a second
>   time because of quantification then its previously-captured value, if
>   any, will be retained if the second evaluation fails. Matching the
>   string "aba" against the expression (a(b)?)+, for example, leaves
>   group two set to "b". All captured input is discarded at the beginning
>   of each match.

Answer (score 0):

Like most other regex flavors, Java doesn't save the intermediate captures of a repeated group.  But that feature isn't really as useful as might think.  For example, the .NET flavor provides the CaptureCollection class for that purpose, but you still have to write the code to loop through it.  Not that big a deal, but still it's usually easier to use multiple matches, like the other responders suggested.  Try it with this regex:

```
"(?:Start:|\\G,)\\s*([\\w\\s]+)"
```

`\G` is a kind of anchor that causes the regex to reject any match that doesn't start exactly where the last match ended.  If there *was* no previous match (i.e., this is the first match attempt), it acts like `\A` and matches only at the very beginning of the string.  That's partly why I placed the `,` in that part of the regex; I think it's safe to assume the string doesn't start with a comma.

Note that the first group is non-capturing; the part you're looking for will always be in 'group(1)`.